# Updating two lists with one JQuery function

Tags: php, jquery

I have a little problem and hoping someone with JQuery knowledge can look at my code and spot what I'm doing wrong.
I have two unordered lists (dynamically created) that get updated with ajax.
With script below I can only get one list to update but not both. I cloned first script and changed variables for second list but only one gets updated.
Thanks for you help.

Here is the html code:

```
  List one: <ul data-options="" class="elgg-list-mainriver elgg-sync elgg-list-river elgg-river"><li> .....</li>
</ul>

List Two:  <ul data-options="" class="elgg-list-miniriver elgg-sync elgg-list-river elgg-river"><li> .....</li>
</ul>
```

And JQuery code:

```
    elgg.provide('elgg.river');

elgg.river.init = function() {

    var riverList = $('ul.elgg-list-mainriver');
    //var miniriverList = $('.elgg-list-miniriver');
    var time = 20000;
    if (!window.rivertimer) {
        window.rivertimer = true;
        var refresh_river = window.setTimeout(function(){
            elgg.river.timedRefresh(riverList);
            //elgg.river.MinitimedRefresh(miniriverList);
        }, time);
    }
};

elgg.river.timedRefresh = function(object) {
    var first = $('li:first', object);
    if (!first.length) {
        first = object;
    }
    var time = first.data('timestamp');

    elgg.getJSON('activity', {
        data : {
            sync : 'new',
            time : time,
            options : object.data('options')
        },
        success : function(output) {
            if (output) {
                $.each(output, function(key, val) {
                    var new_item = $(val).hide();
                    //new_item = $(val).show();
                    object.prepend(new_item.fadeIn(600));
                    //object.prepend(new_item.$(val).show());
                });
            }
            window.rivertimer = false;
            elgg.trigger_hook('success', 'elgg:river:ajax');
        }
    });
}


elgg.provide('elgg.river_miniriver');

elgg.river_miniriver.init = function() {

    var miniriverList = $('ul.elgg-list-miniriver');
    var time = 20000;
    if (!window.rivertimer) {
        window.rivertimer = true;
        var refresh_river = window.setTimeout(function(){
            elgg.river_miniriver.timedRefresh(miniriverList);
        }, time);
    }
};

elgg.river_miniriver.timedRefresh = function(object) {
    var first = $('li:first', object);
    if (!first.length) {
        first = object;
    }
    var time = first.data('timestamp');

    elgg.getJSON('activity', {
        data : {
            sync : 'new',
            time : time,
            options : object.data('options')
        },
        success : function(output) {
            if (output) {
                $.each(output, function(key, val) {
                    var new_item = $(val).hide();
                    //new_item = $(val).show();
                    object.prepend(new_item.fadeIn(600));
                    //object.prepend(new_item.$(val).show());
                });
            }
            window.rivertimer = false;
            elgg.trigger_hook('success', 'elgg:river:ajax');
        }
    });
}

elgg.register_hook_handler('init', 'system', elgg.river.init);
elgg.register_hook_handler('success', 'elgg:river:ajax', elgg.river.init, 500);
elgg.register_hook_handler('init', 'system', elgg.river_miniriver.init);
elgg.register_hook_handler('success', 'elgg:river:ajax', elgg.river_miniriver.init, 500);
```

If I try to combine both lists class in the function "$('ul.elgg-list-miniriver, ul.elgg-list-mainriver')" than both lists get updated but first list item (li) gets "opacity:0;" in style????

This code:

```
elgg.river_miniriver.init = function() {

    var miniriverList = $('ul.elgg-list-miniriver, ul.elgg-list-mainriver');
    var time = 20000;
    if (!window.rivertimer) {
        window.rivertimer = true;
        var refresh_river = window.setTimeout(function(){
            elgg.river_miniriver.timedRefresh(miniriverList);
        }, time);
    }
};

elgg.river_miniriver.timedRefresh = function(object) {
    var first = $('li:first', object);
    if (!first.length) {
        first = object;
    }
    var time = first.data('timestamp');

    elgg.getJSON('activity', {
        data : {
            sync : 'new',
            time : time,
            options : object.data('options')
        },
        success : function(output) {
            if (output) {
                $.each(output, function(key, val) {
                    var new_item = $(val).hide();
                    //new_item = $(val).show();
                    object.prepend(new_item.fadeIn(1000));
                    //object.prepend(new_item.$(val).show());
                });
            }
            window.rivertimer = false;
            elgg.trigger_hook('success', 'elgg:river:ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If I try to combine both lists class in the function than first list item gets "opacity:0;" in style????

Comment: any help? or am I doomed